# Boost.Lambda - dereference placeholder

Tags: boost, boost-function, boost-lambda

Is there a way to dereference a placeholder inside lambda expression ?

```
boost::function<int(MyClass*)> f = _1->myMethod();
f(myObject);
```

I know I can make a binding:

```
boost::function<int(MyClass*)> f = boost::bind(&MyClass::myMethod, _1);
```

, but I want to build more complex expression, with if statements and so on.

Comment: `boost::function<int(Foo*)> func = (_1 ->* &Foo::bla);` should work but does not compile for me and I haven't figured out why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory this should work:

```
struct Foo {
  int bla() { return 2; }
};

boost::function<int(Foo*)> func = (_1 ->* &Foo::bla);
```

There is an [old discussion](http://lists.boost.org/boost-users/2006/11/23754.php) featuring various work-arounds on the
Boost mailing list. All of them seem rather ugly. I'd stick
with nested `bindS` or get a modern C++ compiler.